# Read of IDs of created objects in JMeter?

Tags: rest, jmeter

We have RESTfull web-application.
And we need to make the following test:

```
create 1000 students
view 1000 students
delete 1000 sudents
create 1000 students
view 1000 students
```

We can view object through the following URL: `/students/#id#`.
And for do this we should to known IDs of created objects.
We create students via CSV-files and expect that they are beginning from 1, but if the database isn't clear in begins from bigger number.

How can we read IDs of created students?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're trying to do:

- Create students from data in a CSV file
- View those newly created users
- Delete those users
- Start Over

To get the Student IDs, you need to do a POST-PROCESSOR called Regular Expression Extractor.
It reads the source code and can store specific information into a variable name.

You then pass the variable into the View and Delete Calls.

Link: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor

Your Jmeter Script would look something like this:

- CSV File Configuration
- Request to Create new Students
  --- Regular Expression to grab Student IDS
- Request to view Students
- Request to Delete Students